# Rails model has_many :through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

`User`, `Car`, `Part`, `Tire`.
`User` has many `Car`s. `Car` has many `Part`s. `Part` has many `Tire`s.

In user.rb, I have

```
has_many :tires, through: :cars
```

However, it seems like this is not a correct way of doing it since there is another model `Part` in the middle.

How should I successfully do to make has_many relationships between `User` and `Tire`?

Comment: If you haven't already, take a look at the Rails guide to associations: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html There are really simple examples around many to many associations that should help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add the connection in the middle.

```
# User.rb
has_many :cars
has_many :parts, through: :cars
has_many :tires, through: :parts
```